# converting long xml file into string

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am working on a project where i have to convert `XML` file in the server and then send them into a `JSON` form in the client side

The problem is when I have a large `XML` document since parsing will surpass the limit size of the string.

I even tried changing string into `Byte[]` but the problem my angular client side accept only `JSON` form

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{var1}/{var2}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getGraph(@PathVariable("var1") String var1, @PathVariable("var2") String var2)  {
    byte[] result = loadUnloadWorkflow.loadWorkflow("AMAZONTEST", "FR");
    return new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

is there a way to parse any `XML` file whatever it's size into string ?

Comment: What's the size of the XML? Isn't it just TOO big? In String you can store up to `MAX_INT` characters. You may also be exceeding your heap memory. Is it the case? Btw, what's the output/exception there?

Comment: You can parse XML file with streaming which doesn't load the whole DOM, but then you'll have the same problem when serializing into JSON I suppose. So maybe change the client side so that it accepts a stream. It should be the preferred way to download large files.

Comment: @Pijotrek there's no exceptio for the moment i am working with small one now to the test, i am just wondering about bigger files

Comment: @grape_mao i prefer json form because it's easy to work with , even http angular accept only json form

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert the XML to an object and then, convert the object to json. What about that?